# I can't find the flycheck package

Tags: package, flycheck

I am on MacOS and using Emacs 26.3

When I go to package-install in the minibuffer and type in flycheck, it autocompletes and adds a hyphen. I can't install just flycheck. Also when I go to list-packages, flycheck is missing. I have refreshed packages and I followed the installation instructions on flycheck.org exactly, and I am using melpa. I attached a picture:

[image]

Comment: `M-x package-install` doesn't show installed packages, is flycheck already installed? When you have a package installed, the package menu (M-x list-package) will mention the package "installed" or "dependency".

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed flycheck was already installed.